# equivalence pdf for the difference of n normal distribution functions

Tags: statistics

I know about the equivalence pdf for the sum of n normal distribution functions, is which their convolution.

Could you please explain the pdf for the case of subtracting n normal distributions?...

Thanks in advance

Edit: I mean something like this by "subtracting of N normal distributions":

Y = (...((X1 - X2) - X3) - X4) - ...)... )

Comment: I am not sure what *subtracting $n$ normal distributions* really means, but for $n=2$ you might try multiplying one normal distribution by $-1$ (since its distribution is symmetric about the mean, this in effects reverse the sign of its mean, or can be treated as a location change) and then add them.

Comment: @Henry: That sounds much reasonable! I acquired X~N(mu_0 - mu_1, sig_0^2 + sig_1^2) for the case of two distributions. But I am not sure about the crediblity of the result...

Comment: If the two normal random variables are independent then that looks correct

Comment: @Henry: Please check the edit. Itried to clear `subtracting n normal distributions`. Have you any idea about it, now?! Can I extend the result of above case for N RVs?! i.e. X~N(mu_0 + mu_1 + ... + mu_N, sig_0^2 + sig_1^2 + ... + sig_N^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any linear combination of independent normal random variables is normal.
The mean and variance are the appropriate combinations of the means and variances of the individual random variables.  Thus if $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$ and are independent, then 
$$X_1 - X_2 - \ldots - X_n \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2 - \ldots - \mu_n, 
\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2)$$

Comment: @Thank you... That is exactly what I was looking for...